# Почему после закрытия скрипт висит в процессах?

Tags: python, gtk

Только начал изучать PyGTK. Сразу, дабы в будущем облегчить себе жизнь, я пишу свои классы и функции по изученным материалам.

Такой вопрос: после закрытия скрипт висит в процессах. Как это исправить? Сразу скажу, что данный класс планируется использовать для программы, у которой нет интерфейса (она висит в трее), а необходимость, посредством информационных окон, доносить результаты работы к пользователю остается. Поправьте, пожалуйста, если я где-то допустил ошибку.

```
import gtk

# Константы кнопок.
YES = gtk.BUTTONS_OK
YES_NO = gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO
YES_CANCEL = gtk.BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL
CLOSE = gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE

# Константы окон.
INFO = gtk.MESSAGE_INFO
QUERY = gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION
WARNING = gtk.MESSAGE_WARNING
ERROR = gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR

class PyGtkDialog(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyGtkDialog, self).__init__()

    def __show(self, widget, title, text, buttons, par):
        window = gtk.MessageDialog(self, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL, par, buttons, text)
        window.set_title(title)
        response = window.run()
        result = None

        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_YES or response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            result = "yes"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
            result = "cancel"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CLOSE:
            result = "close"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_NO:
            result = "no"

        window.destroy()
        return result

    def show(self, title="Title", text="Text", buttons=CLOSE, par=INFO):
        result = self.__show(self, title, text, buttons, par)
        gtk.main()
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gtk_dialog = PyGtkDialog()
    result = gtk_dialog.show("Заголовок", "Текст", YES_CANCEL, WARNING)
    print result
```

Comment: А почему именно GTK?

Comment: Я долгое время пользовался Tkinter. Пробовал PyQt. Но после нескольких глав и примеров из туториалов ничего, кроме раздражения и, порою, ненависти к аллогичному синтаксису, архитектуре классов и сигналов, он у меня не вызвал. PyGTK более человеческий, логикой схож с простым, как три копейки, Tkinter, и ничем не уступает Qt, за это его и выбрал!

Comment: Мне не совсем понятна цель вызова gtk.main() в данном примере. Зачем он здесь нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если без вызова gtk.main(), то мой вариант таков:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2

import gtk
import os;
# Константы кнопок.
YES = gtk.BUTTONS_OK
YES_NO = gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO
YES_CANCEL = gtk.BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL
CLOSE = gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE

# Константы окон.
INFO = gtk.MESSAGE_INFO
QUERY = gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION
WARNING = gtk.MESSAGE_WARNING
ERROR = gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR

class PyGtkDialog(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyGtkDialog, self).__init__()

    def __show(self, widget, title, text, buttons, par):
        window = gtk.MessageDialog(self, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL, par, buttons, text)
        window.set_title(title)
        response = window.run()
        result = None

        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_YES or response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            result = "yes"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL:
            result = "cancel"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_CLOSE:
            result = "close"
        elif response == gtk.RESPONSE_NO:
            result = "no"

        window.destroy()
        return result

    def show(self, title="Заголовок", text="Текст", buttons=CLOSE, par=INFO):
        result = self.__show(self, title, text, buttons, par)
        #gtk.main()
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gtk_dialog = PyGtkDialog()
    result = gtk_dialog.show("Приложение будет закрыто!", "Выйти?", YES_CANCEL, WARNING)
    if result == 'yes':
        os.sys.exit()
```

Comment: Да, все правильно, закоментировал gtk.main(). Я считал, что это аналог mainloop в Tkinter, спасибо!

Comment: Если хотите создать приложение в трее на PyGTK, не мучайтесь, а возьмите сразу заготовку, например, здесь
http://eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Systray%20icon.html

Comment: Спасибо, как раз только что начал переписывать подобный класс с Tkinter на PyGTK!

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в gtk, но не вижу в коде корректного завершения приложения. Что-то вроде `gtk.close()`, или `gtk.exit()`, или `gtk_dialog.close()`. У Вас продолжает выполнятся главный цикл обработки событий `gtk.main()`, `gtk_dialog` надо правильно закрыть.

Comment: C gtk.main_quit() скрипт тоже становится висяком.

Comment: После выполнения функций ГУИ, закройте главный фрейм (gtk_dialog).

Answer (score 0):

```
def __destroy(self,widget):
    gtk.main_quit()
    pass

win=gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
win.connect('destroy',self.__destroy)
```

Прекрасно закрывает приложение.